# Angular 4 Material 2 Remove placeholder superscript and error subscript space from input controls

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

I am currently attempting to use some components from angular material inside a material styled table. The issue I'm having is that even though I can floatPlaceholder="never" and shouldPlaceholderFloat="false", the space above the control is still taken up by the placeholder. The same goes for the error text that sits below the input line.

I want a consistent row height, and so do not want the placeholder space or error line space taken up. But I do want the behaviour where the underline highlights when the control is clicked (which you don't get if you take the control out of the form field.)

[image: Angular Material placeholder and error space]

How can I get rid of or hide this space?

Here's the code:

```
<form>

  <div style='background-color:lightblue'>

    <mat-form-field style='background-color:lightgreen' floatPlaceholder="never" shouldPlaceholderFloat="false">
      <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="food">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
          {{food.viewValue}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

    <p> Selected value: {{selectedValue}} </p>
  </div>
</form>
```

I have provided a plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/nkYoANFqXYZyen7aUJ7g).

Comment: You can do it by overriding the style classes along with using `ViewEncapsulation.None`, however, that will be against Material Design principles.

Comment: I had a go at a css solution but couldn't get it to override the right styles. (And yes, I am aware that I might be violating the principles, but I need it for this scenario as the control it is sitting in has limitations of its own. )

Comment: Ok, it turns out my problem was not putting ViewEncapsulation.None. After that, I could modify styles - Angular was stripping out my styles.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me
(Material version 5)

in your component overwrite material classes to :

```
.mat-form-field-infix {
    border-top: 0 solid transparent !important;
}
.mat-form-field-wrapper {
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}
.mat-form-field-underline {
    bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

and you may want to add `floatLabel="never"` to your `mat-form-field` element to disable your place holder from hovering above your input as well.